# Issue with directing php form

Tags: php, html, sql, forms, function

```
<?php
    if ($_POST['submit'] == "submit")
    {
    $userName = $_POST['username'];
    $passWord = $_POST['password'];

$db= mysql_connect("localhost", "root", "root");
        if(!$db) die("Error connecting to MySQL database.");
        mysql_select_db("onlineform", $db);


$checkUserNameQuery = "SELECT username FROM onlineformdata ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 1";
$checkUserName = mysql_query($checkUserNameQuery);
$checkPassWordQuery = "SELECT password FROM onlineformdata ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 1";
$checkPassWord = mysql_query($checkPassWordQuery);
$AdminChanges = "";

if (($userName == $checkUserName) && ($passWord == $checkPassWord)) 
    {
    $AdminChanges = "AdminChanges.php";
    }
else 
    {
    $AdminChanges = "InvalidLogin.html";
    }
}

function PrepSQL($value)
    {
        // Stripslashes
        if(get_magic_quotes_gpc()) 
        {
            $value = stripslashes($value);
        }

        // Quote
        $value = "'" . mysql_real_escape_string($value) . "'";

        return($value);
    }

?>
<html>
<head>
<title>Admin Login</title>
</head>
<body>
<form action = <?php echo PrepSQL($AdminChanges); ?>  method="post">
username: <input type="text" name="username" />
password: <input type="text" name="password" /> <br/>

<input type="submit" name="submit" value="submit" />
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

I'm having a problem where the form, when submitted, is being directed to the wrong places. It's a user verification page. If the username and password don't match the ones stored in the database, it should go to the Invalid Login page. If they do, they should go to the next part of the user verification website.

The form tag, before entering values, looks like this in the page source:

However, when the username & password are correct, it goes to the InvalidLogin.html page. When it's incorrect, the form reloads again and when I check the page source, it's the exact same code except now the form tag shows:

Any suggestions?

Comment: uh, why are you doing SQL escaping for a value that's being used in an HTML context? You still haven't corrected the fundamental problems with your code, namely that you're using the two queries COMPLETELY wrong (you're comparing strings against result handles), your code does not account for multiple user accounts and will only validate against the FIRST account retrieved from the db, etc... You have not fundamentally changed anything in this code since you started asking these repeated questions. And to boot, for all your talk of redirecting, nowhere in your code do you actually redirect.

Comment: Please fix your indentation first.

Answer (score 0):

I think u got it wrong, the action tag is where the form sends the request, not where to go after it sends it.

Try using [header('location: '.$AdminChanges);](http://php.net/manual/en/function.header.php) right after the user verification in order to redirect the page.

EDIT: Also remove the action tag of the form. By removing it the request will be sent to the same file you are working on.

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
    if($_POST['username'] && $_POST['password']){

        $username = $_POST['username']; // Escape this
        $password = $_POST['password']; // Escape this

        $searchQuery = mysql_query("SELECT id FROM onlineformdata WHERE username = '$userName' AND password = '$password' ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 1");

        if(mysql_num_rows($searchQuery)){
            header('location:/adminPage.php'); // Go to this page if row exists in DB
        }
        else{
            header('location:/invalidLoginPage.html'); //Go to this page if row doesn't exist in DB
        }

        exit; // So that it quite this page and goes to the desired one set in the "headers"
    }
    else{
        //Not strictly needed... But you could be useful in some circumstances
    }
?>

<html>
<head>
<title>Admin Login</title>
</head>
<body>
<form action=''  method="post">
username: <input type="text" name="username" />
password: <input type="text" name="password" /> <br/>

<input type="submit" value="submit" />
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

This should get you started in the *right* direction. Don't forget to escape the username/password fields as you see fit.

The *action* part of the form is where the form is submitted to and so - in your case - that should be the same page. As Hristo said, you can leave it out/blank and it will default to submitting itself.

As for Marc B (he did ask a question after all); if you read the code you would see that the PrepSQL function actually adds single quotes around the string... As there are no quotes in the html this isn't wrong in anyway... So I don't see what the problem is there (aside from it not doing what he wanted it to).

With regards to multiple user accounts, so long as you don't allow the same *username* to be used by multiple users then there is only one record returned by the database... So again, there's no problem there.